# Bootloop after lpunpack super image and repack with lpmake

Tags: rom-flashing, custom-roms

I have a Poco X6 Pro phone, I wanted to edit the device partitions to remove some bloatware apk.

I backed up the `super.img` partition with `dd` in termux. If I flash the `super.img` with `fastboot flash super super.img` it works perfectly, so the partition is ok.

I wanted to extract the internal partitions, mount them and edit them, but whatever I do, it seems I corrupt the `super.img` and flashing it makes the device go in bootloop.

So I tried to do NO MODIFICATIONS at all, simply convert the **sparsed** `super.img` to **unsparsed** with `simg2img` tool. This worked well.

Then I extracted the `super_unsparsed.img` with `lpunpack` tool, returning me the raw .img files, here is the list with the block size:

```
mi_ext_b.img 656302080
odm_b.img 645382144
odm_dlkm_b.img 31739904
product_b.img 3548254208
super_unsparsed.img 9663676416
system_b.img 1080905728
system_dlkm_b.img 43270144
system_ext_b.img 942575616
vendor_b.img 2614239232
vendor_dlkm_b.img 80011264
```

And now I try to repack using `lpmake` command, without touching the partitions:

```
lpmake --metadata-size 65536 \
--super-name super --metadata-slots 2 --virtual-ab \
--device super:9663676416 \
--group xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a:9663676416 \
--partition=mi_ext_a:none:656302080:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=odm_a:none:645382144:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=odm_dlkm_a:none:31739904:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=product_a:none:3548254208:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=system_a:none:1080905728:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=system_dlkm_a:none:43270144:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=system_ext_a:none:942575616:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=vendor_a:none:2614239232:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--partition=vendor_dlkm_a:none:80011264:xiaomi_dynamic_partitions_a \
--image=mi_ext_a=mi_ext_b.img \
--image=odm_a=odm_b.img \
--image=odm_dlkm_a=odm_dlkm_b.img \
--image=product_a=product_b.img \
--image=system_a=system_b.img \
--image=system_dlkm_a=system_dlkm_b.img \
--image=system_ext_a=system_ext_b.img \
--image=vendor_a=vendor_b.img \
--image=vendor_dlkm_a=vendor_dlkm_b.img \
--sparse \
--output ./super.new.img
```

Here is the output of the command:

```
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition mi_ext_a will resize from 0 bytes to 656302080 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition odm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 645382144 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition odm_dlkm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 31739904 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition product_a will resize from 0 bytes to 3548254208 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition system_a will resize from 0 bytes to 1080905728 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition system_dlkm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 43270144 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition system_ext_a will resize from 0 bytes to 942575616 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition vendor_a will resize from 0 bytes to 2614239232 bytes
lpmake I 03-27 20:48:45   475   475 builder.cpp:1093] [liblp]Partition vendor_dlkm_a will resize from 0 bytes to 80011264 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
```

In the end, I flash the `super.new.img` with `fastboot flash super super.new.img`

But results in bootloop. (Also, `fastboot set_active a` or `b` does not change the result)